# URL parsing program does not stop looping

Tags: java

Requirements:

1. I need to accept a string as an argument
2. prints out the first link it find
3. returns an integer that is the index of the link End or -1 if
   no links are found.

An if statement if it does not find "href" in the string it will return the integer, An if statement to return the -1 before the substring method will keep from getting an index out of bounds error.

The display need to return all the http sites in the string.

I believe i am very close, here is my code:

```
public class LinkList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String htmlCode = (a long string with all my url links)


    int linkStart = 0;
    int endLink = 0;
    while (true) {
        linkStart = hrefSearch(htmlCode);
        if(linkStart == -1) break;
        htmlCode = htmlCode.substring(linkStart);
    } 

} 

public static int hrefSearch (String inStr) {

    String find = " href=";
    String closingBracket = ">";


     int index = inStr.indexOf(find);

     if (index != -1){
        int closing = inStr.indexOf(closingBracket, index);

     if (closing != -1){
        System.out.println(inStr.substring (index, closing + 1));

        }
}
    return index;
}}
```

How can i get my program to stop looping and display all the urls in my string?

Comment: You should start by reading the Help Center. There's a lot of noise in your question body and title, but no actual question.

Comment: What output does your code produce? What doesn't work?

Comment: Wouldn't `"href="` be more appropriate?

Comment: well it keeps looping and only displays one of the urls which should be more in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
htmlCode = htmlCode.substring(linkStart);
```

to:

```
htmlCode = htmlCode.substring(linkStart+1);
```

Otherwise, you'll keep finding the first URL over and over again (since `linkStart` is the position where the previous URL starts, so `htmlCode.substring(linkStart)` still contains the previous URL you found).

Comment: I was beating my head against the keyboard all day for something that small.

Comment: I will be posting another problem with another program i am having. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @jc If I see it and can answer it, I might (assuming someone else doesn't answer it first). BTW, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: how do i accept the answer, i am new to this website.

Comment: @jc Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a good idea to check the help links at the top right of the page. You accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.